# How to apply Slicer filters while embedding power Bi report in a web page

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am embedding power Bi report in a page where I am able to apply page level filters perfectly using the below-mentioned code

```
const basicFilter1 = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
  target: {
      table: 'xTable',
      column: "xColumn"
  },
  operator: "In",
  values: [value1],
  filterType: 1 // pbi.models.FilterType.BasicFilter
  };
var embedConfiguration = {
    type: "report",
    id: res.reportid,
    embedUrl:res.embedurl,
    accessToken:res.token,
    filters: [basicFilter1]  
};
```

Now I have two slicers in my report and I have to apply filter to those slicers with different value.

Comment: This is not a question. Please review the [How to ask a good question section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and complete your question with an actual question.

Comment: There is no official supported way to do that.